# Inkscape Font-specific Baseline Drop in Flow Region (Text Box)

Tags: fonts, inkscape

When I change my font, my baseline drops inside of a `flowRegion` (text box).  Specifically the `Cardo` font (I have not noticed others); see the image below.

[image: Various baseline drops]

**How do I adjust the baseline so the font starts at the top of the text region?**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Get/install the [Cardo Font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cardo)
2. Open Inkscape 0.91 (Windows 7?)
3. Draw a text box
4. Type text
5. *See its baseline where you would expect*
6. Select text and choose `Cardo` font
7. *See its baseline drop* **bad**

For what it is worth, this was not a problem in the past, likely with a previous version of Inkscape (0.48?).  I discovered the problem when opening a previous .svg file and found my text was missing (well, it was not missing it was just too low to see).

Comment: Hey jtooker and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works